# Test inside function condition is true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have function like this

```
export const fun1= (): string => {
  const onSessionExpiryForDateTime = '2021-12-01 11:00:00'
 const list: any = sessionStorage.getItem('removeItem');
 if (list) {
  const listSession: any = JSON.parse(list);
 if (true) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('removeItem');
 }
  }  
   return onSessionExpiryForDateTime;
 };
```

I am trying to write unit test case I need like if true then session shoud remove

Here I am trying to write test

```
it('Should remove session key  date and time ', () => {
  const spyOnFn = jest.spyOn(service, 'fun1');
  const getCacheKeyRemoveItem = jest.spyOn(sessionStorage, 'removeItem');
  const isCached = true;
  if (isCached) {
    expect(sessionStorage.removeItem(SESSION_KEY)).toBeUndefined();
  }
  expect(getCacheKeyRemoveItem).toBeCalledWith(SESSION_KEY);
  expect(spyOnFn).toBeCalled();
});
```

but my test is failing. where I am doing wrong

Comment: _"but my test is failing"_. We can't see what you see.Please provide the details about what exactly is failing. There must be some error messages or failed assertions.

Comment: Please let me know if (isCached) {
    expect(sessionStorage.removeItem(SESSION_KEY)).toBeUndefined();
  } is correct  ? expect(spyOnFn).toBeCalled(); is failing itself

Comment: How is it failing? What is the message? Please be a bit more precise.

Comment: What are you trying to test with `expect(sessionStorage.removeItem(SESSION_KEY)).toBeUndefined();`? `removeItem()` always returns `undefined` by definition. You don't need to test an internal of a built-in browser API.